# How to pass this Day 1 to next view controller as uilabel and I want to print Day 1 in next page

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

```
UILabel * lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake​(920, 0, 280, 50)];
 lbl.text=@"DAY 1";
 lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:30]];
 [self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

How to pass this Day 1 to next view controller as uilabel and I want to print Day 1 in next page

Comment: Use UserDefaults to carry the values,to next viewcontroller.

Comment: That only i dono how to carry my label to next page..

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom initilaiser for your viewcontroller that takes the data you want to pass to it.

i.e. `[[MyUIViewController alloc]initWithMyData:(MyClass*)data]`

then have the viewcontroller set the value of its label to what ever was passed in.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what you're asking, what do you mean write anything? i'd gladly give you an idea for that if I knew what you wanted :)